# Simplify mathematics expression programmatically

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to simplify the expression into more natural form in which

- `-2pi/2` becomes `-pi`
- `-1pi/2` becomes `-pi/2`,
- `0pi/2` becomes `0`,
- `1pi/2` becomes `pi/2`,
- `2pi/2` becomes `pi`?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw   (-pi,0) -- (pi,0);
    \draw \foreach \i in {-2,-1,0,...,2}{(\i*pi/2,-.1) node[below, font=\tiny] {$\i\pi/2$} -- (\i*pi/2,.1)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest sagemath for simplifying mathematical expressions. It can also export latex, and execute from inside a latex document.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I introduce `\simplifyhalves{<index>}{<term>}` which will present in math mode a reduced version of `<index><term>/2`.

EDITED to filter out the special cases of `-1\pi` as `-\pi`, `1\pi` as `\pi`, and `0\pi` as `0`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\let\stripPT\strip@pt
\makeatother
\newcommand\simplifyhalves[2]{%
  \def\j{\stripPT\dimexpr.5\dimexpr#1 pt\relax\relax}%
  \ifodd#1%
    $\i#2/2$%
  \else%
    \def\theterm{#2}%
    \ifnum\j=-1\relax\def\j{-}%
    \else%
      \ifnum\j=1\relax%
        \def\j{}%
      \else
        \ifnum\j=0\relax%
          \def\theterm{}%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \fi%
    $\j\theterm$%
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw   (-pi,0) -- (pi,0);
    \draw \foreach \i in {-2,-1,0,...,2}{(\i*pi/2,-.1) node[below, font=\tiny] {%
      \simplifyhalves{\i}{\pi}} -- (\i*pi/2,.1)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `-1pi` must be simplified into `-pi`.

Comment: @SinglePackAbs I have EDITED to create the macro `\simplifyhalves`.

Answer (score 18):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw   (-pi,0) -- (pi,0);
    \foreach \i [count=\j from -2] in {-\pi,-\pi/2,0,\pi/2,\pi}
        \draw (\j*pi/2,.1) -- + (0,-0.2) node[below, font=\tiny] {$\i$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't like manual labor in `{-\pi,-\pi/2,0,\pi/2,\pi}`.

Comment: well, than you not like simple solutions :).  you have one "programmatic" answer more ...